# Problem in finding missing values in big dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe, machine-learning, dataset, missing-data

As you can see in the image there are 563 columns and I can't see full missing values in this case because jupyter-notebook in showing it briefly what should I do in this case.
For reference I tried with `both.isnull().sum()`

Here is the actual code I tried for this problem:

```
both.isnull().sum()

tBodyAcc-mean()-X       0
tBodyAcc-mean()-Y       0
tBodyAcc-mean()-Z       0
tBodyAcc-std()-X        0
tBodyAcc-std()-Y        0
                       ..
angle(Z,gravityMean)    0
subject                 0
Activity                0
Data                    0
Subject                 0
Length: 565, dtype: int64
```

Comment: `both.info()` ? Your question is not clear. Do you want to know how many null values are in each column??? Then `both.info()` . What is your specific questions and desired result?

Comment: Not null values I just want to know about missing values , and even for info jupyter notebook is still summerizing it so i can't see full output

Comment: what you mean by "missing values"? "Blank" values ? i.e. ` `

Comment: Yes None or blank columns

Comment: For those we actually use mean or medium to fill that gap

Comment: @DeepanshuDashora Does YOLO answer answer your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to set [`global options`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/options.html) like:

```
pd.set_option('max_colwidth', 256)
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', 1000)
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 1000)
```

I often set these three to some big number, however if you want to see even more data, set them to `None`.

Comment: @DeepanshuDashora if it helps, please accept the answer.

Comment: @DeepanshuDashora Once the problem is solved just click on the checkmark (to the left of the answer, which should turn green, letting the system know that the question has been solved.

Answer (score -1):

You can make a heatmap to explore this,
you need to install `seaborn` like `pip install seaborn`

```
sns.heatmap(both.isnull())
```

with any color you want

Comment: But in the heatmap method it is still not showing proper output with all the column names and even I can't see the names properly of columns

Comment: `sns.heatmap(train.isnull(),yticklabels=False,cbar=False,cmap='viridis')`

Comment: use this it will give you a good output.
and set the figure size acc. to you

Comment: i would like it if you could just upvote the answer if you are satisfied.